# Custom type converter for Mojo configuration?

Tags: type-conversion, maven-plugin, mojo, custom-type

I need to use custom type, e.g., `LunarDate`, in my Mojo object:

```
class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /** @parameter */
    LunarDate lunarDate;

}
```

And I want to configure the parameter in `<configuration>` section in pom.xml.

```
<configuration>
     <lunarDate>丁丑年二月初四</lunarDate>
</configuration>
```

(The type `LunarDate` is just an example to illustrate the question)

I've already had the type converters, but how to enable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultBeanConfigurator` is responsible for using `DefaultConverterLookup`, and it instantiates it directly without using the Plexus Container.

You could I suppose copy and modify it in a build extension, but registering your copy via `@Component(role=BeanConfigurator.class)` will likely have no effect; I have tried replacing standard Maven components in the past from build extensions and been told on maven-dev that it is not possible.

You could look up the default `BeanConfigurator` and use reflection to get its `ConverterLookup converterLookup` field, then call `registerConverter` with your custom convertor, but this would be fragile.

Probably best is to just give up, declare your Mojo parameter to be of type `String`, and do the conversion explicitly in `execute`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by defining a ConfigurationConverter (my target
type is a AnyLicenseInfo):

```java
@NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class LicenseConverter extends AbstractBasicConverter {
    private static final Class<?> TYPE = AnyLicenseInfo.class;

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class<?> type) { return type.equals(TYPE); }

    @Override
    public Object fromString(String string) throws ComponentConfigurationException {
        Object object = null;

        try {
            object =
                TYPE.cast(LicenseInfoFactory.parseSPDXLicenseString(string));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            String message =
                "Unable to convert '" + string + "' to " + TYPE.getName();

            throw new ComponentConfigurationException(message, exception);
        }

        return object;
    }
}
```

Registering it with a custom ComponentConfigurator:

```java
@Named("license-mojo-component-configurator")
@NoArgsConstructor @ToString @Slf4j
public class LicenseMojoComponentConfigurator extends BasicComponentConfigurator {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        converterLookup.registerConverter(new LicenseConverter());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

And then specifying the configurator in the @Mogo annotation:

```java
@Mojo(name = "generate-license-resources",
      configurator = "license-mojo-component-configurator",
      requiresDependencyResolution = TEST,
      defaultPhase = GENERATE_RESOURCES, requiresProject = true)
@NoArgsConstructor @ToString @Slf4j
public class GenerateLicenseResourcesMojo extends AbstractLicenseMojo {
```

Comment: Hi! Could you specify which maven version you were using? It works well on mvn `v3.8.6`, but fails on `v3.6.3`.

Comment: Yes, I currently compile against Maven 3.8.6.  FWIW, I have since published my pluginn at https://github.com/allen-ball/ball-license-maven-plugin and I created the initial version of the plugin when 3.6.3 was the latest Maven.

Answer (score 0):

For newer Maven (tested with Maven 3.3.1) you can now subclass `BasicComponentConfigurator` to access the `DefaultConverterLookup` as a member variable:

```java
@Component(role = ComponentConfigurator.class, hint = "basic")
public class ExtendedComponentRegistrator 
        extends BasicComponentConfigurator  
        implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize() throws InitializationException {
        converterLookup.registerConverter(new MyCustomConverter());
    }
}
```

Then in the pom.xml enable the generation of plexus meta data:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-component-metadata</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate-metadata</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```