# Using map of maps as Maven plugin parameters

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is it possible to use a map of maps as a Maven plugin parameter?, e.g.

```java
@Parameter
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> converters;
```

and then to use it like

```
<converters>
  <json>
     <indent>true</indent>
     <strict>true</strict>
  </json>
  <yaml>
      <stripComments>false</stripComments>
  </yaml>
<converters>
```

If I use it like this, `converters` only contain the keys `json` and `yaml` with null as values.

I know it is possible to have complex objects as values, but is it also somehow possible to use maps for variable element values like in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is quite simple and works for 1-level nesting. A more sophisticated approach can be found in the alternative answer which possibly also allows for deeper nesting of Maps.

Instead of using an interface as type parameter, simply use a concrete class like `TreeMap`

```java
 @Parameter
 private Map<String, TreeMap> converters.
```

The reason is this check in [MapConverter](https://github.com/eclipse/sisu.plexus/blob/releases/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus/src/org/codehaus/plexus/component/configurator/converters/composite/MapConverter.java#L124) which fails for an interface but suceeds for a concrete class:

```java
   private static Class<?> findElementType( final Type[] typeArguments )
   {
       if ( null != typeArguments && typeArguments.length > 1 
            && typeArguments[1] instanceof Class<?> )
       {
           return (Class<?>) typeArguments[1];
       }
       return Object.class;
   }
```

As a side-note, an as it is also related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188534/custom-type-converter-for-mojo-configuration) for Maven > 3.3.x it also works to install a custom converter by subclassing `BasicComponentConfigurator` and using it as a Plexus component. `BasicComponentConfigurator` has the `DefaultConverterLookup` as a protected member variable and is hence easily accessible for registering custom converters.

Comment: Would it be theoretically possible to configure my map keys using *attributes* instead of the element names, using this converter technique?

Answer (score 6):

This is apparently a limitation of the [sisu.plexus](https://github.com/eclipse/sisu.plexus) project internally used by the Mojo API. If you peek inside the [`MapConverter`](https://github.com/eclipse/sisu.plexus/blob/releases/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus/src/org/codehaus/plexus/component/configurator/converters/composite/MapConverter.java#L62) source, you'll find out that it first tries to fetch the value of the map by trying to interpret the configuration as a String (invoking `fromExpression`), and when this fails, [looks up the expected type of the value](https://github.com/eclipse/sisu.plexus/blob/releases/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus/src/org/codehaus/plexus/component/configurator/converters/composite/MapConverter.java#L122-L129). However this method doesn't check for [parameterized types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html), which is our case here (since the type of the map value is `Map<String, String>`). I filed [the bug 498757](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=498757) on the Bugzilla of this project to track this.

### Using a custom wrapper object

One workaround would be to not use a `Map<String, String>` as value but use a custom object:

```java
@Parameter
private Map<String, Converter> converters;
```

with a class `Converter`, located in the same package as the Mojo, being:

```java
public class Converter {

    @Parameter
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    @Override
    public String toString() { return properties.toString(); } // to test

}
```

You can then configure your Mojo with:

```
<converters>
  <json>
    <properties>
      <indent>true</indent>
      <strict>true</strict>
    </properties>
  </json>
  <yaml>
    <properties>
      <stripComments>false</stripComments>
    </properties>
  </yaml>
</converters>
```

This configuration will correctly inject the values in the inner-maps. It also keeps the variable aspect: the object is only introduced as a wrapper around the inner-map. I tested this with a simple test mojo having

```java
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    getLog().info(converters.toString());
}
```

and the output was the expected `{json={indent=true, strict=true}, yaml={stripComments=false}}`.

### Using a custom configurator

I also found a way to keep a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` by using a custom `ComponentConfigurator`.

So we want to fix `MapConverter` by inhering it, the trouble is how to register this new `FixedMapConverter`. By default, Maven uses a `BasicComponentConfigurator` to configure the Mojo and it relies on a `DefaultConverterLookup` to look-up for converters to use for a specific class. In this case, we want to provide a custom converted for `Map` that will return our fixed version. Therefore, we need to extend this basic configurator and register our new converter.

```java
import org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ConfigurationListener;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.expression.ExpressionEvaluator;
import org.codehaus.plexus.configuration.PlexusConfiguration;

public class CustomBasicComponentConfigurator extends BasicComponentConfigurator {
    @Override
    public void configureComponent(final Object component, final PlexusConfiguration configuration,
            final ExpressionEvaluator evaluator, final ClassRealm realm, final ConfigurationListener listener)
            throws ComponentConfigurationException {
        converterLookup.registerConverter(new FixedMapConverter());
        super.configureComponent(component, configuration, evaluator, realm, listener);
    }
}
```

Then we need to tell Maven to use this new configurator instead of the basic one. This is a 2-step process:

1. Inside your Maven plugin, create a file `src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml` registering the new component:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <component-set>
     <components>
       <component>
         <role>org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurator</role>
         <role-hint>custom-basic</role-hint>
         <implementation>package.to.CustomBasicComponentConfigurator</implementation>
       </component>
     </components>
   </component-set>
   ```

   Note a few things: we declare a new component having the hint `"custom-basic"`, this will serve as an id to refer to it and the `<implementation>` refers to the fully qualified class name of our configurator.
2. Tell our Mojo to use this configurator with the [`configurator`](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html#The_Descriptor_and_Annotations) attribute of the `@Mojo` annotation:

   ```java
   @Mojo(name = "test", configurator = "custom-basic")
   ```

   The configurator passed here corresponds to the role-hint specified in the `components.xml` above.

With such a set-up, you can finally declare

```java
@Parameter
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> converters;
```

and everything will be injected properly: Maven will use our custom configurator, that will register our fixed version of the map converter and will correctly convert the inner-maps.

---

Full code of `FixedMapConverter` (which pretty much copy-pastes `MapConverter` because we can't override the faulty method):

```java
public class FixedMapConverter extends MapConverter {

    public Object fromConfiguration(final ConverterLookup lookup, final PlexusConfiguration configuration,
            final Class<?> type, final Type[] typeArguments, final Class<?> enclosingType, final ClassLoader loader,
            final ExpressionEvaluator evaluator, final ConfigurationListener listener)
            throws ComponentConfigurationException {
        final Object value = fromExpression(configuration, evaluator, type);
        if (null != value) {
            return value;
        }
        try {
            final Map<Object, Object> map = instantiateMap(configuration, type, loader);
            final Class<?> elementType = findElementType(typeArguments);
            if (Object.class == elementType || String.class == elementType) {
                for (int i = 0, size = configuration.getChildCount(); i < size; i++) {
                    final PlexusConfiguration element = configuration.getChild(i);
                    map.put(element.getName(), fromExpression(element, evaluator));
                }
                return map;
            }
            // handle maps with complex element types...
            final ConfigurationConverter converter = lookup.lookupConverterForType(elementType);
            for (int i = 0, size = configuration.getChildCount(); i < size; i++) {
                Object elementValue;
                final PlexusConfiguration element = configuration.getChild(i);
                try {
                    elementValue = converter.fromConfiguration(lookup, element, elementType, enclosingType, //
                            loader, evaluator, listener);
                }
                // TEMP: remove when http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHADE-168
                // is fixed
                catch (final ComponentConfigurationException e) {
                    elementValue = fromExpression(element, evaluator);

                    Logs.warn("Map in " + enclosingType + " declares value type as: {} but saw: {} at runtime",
                            elementType, null != elementValue ? elementValue.getClass() : null);
                }
                // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                map.put(element.getName(), elementValue);
            }
            return map;
        } catch (final ComponentConfigurationException e) {
            if (null == e.getFailedConfiguration()) {
                e.setFailedConfiguration(configuration);
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<Object, Object> instantiateMap(final PlexusConfiguration configuration, final Class<?> type,
            final ClassLoader loader) throws ComponentConfigurationException {
        final Class<?> implType = getClassForImplementationHint(type, configuration, loader);
        if (null == implType || Modifier.isAbstract(implType.getModifiers())) {
            return new TreeMap<Object, Object>();
        }

        final Object impl = instantiateObject(implType);
        failIfNotTypeCompatible(impl, type, configuration);
        return (Map<Object, Object>) impl;
    }

    private static Class<?> findElementType( final Type[] typeArguments )
    {
        if ( null != typeArguments && typeArguments.length > 1 )
        {
            if ( typeArguments[1] instanceof Class<?> )
            {
                return (Class<?>) typeArguments[1];
            }
            // begin fix here
            if ( typeArguments[1] instanceof ParameterizedType )
            {
                return (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) typeArguments[1]).getRawType();
            }
            // end fix here
        }
        return Object.class;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ! So it seems, that you can use maps or properties only in every second level (which adds a bit to the boilerplate because the intermediate level is really not needed. It seems however that it _can_ lookup a type parameter (or how could it detect then "Converter" as a type otherwise?), but that does not work for another generic type like map.

Comment: @RolandHuß Yes the converter recognizes classes as complex types but it doesn't handle a parameterized type. I made an issue on the Bugzilla of the project here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=498757 and it is being taken into account.

Comment: Could it be a workaround to write a custom `ConfigurationConverter` which kicks in e.g. on a `MapHandler` class and returns a `Map` from its `fromConfiguration()` method. The plugin then would declare a `@Parameter private Map<String,MapHandler> myMap` parameter. I wonder how custom configuration converters can be registered, though.

Comment: @RolandHuß I finally found a way to do it without having a new object!

Comment: Me, too ;-) See below and also my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188534/custom-type-converter-for-mojo-configuration Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: For me a role hint of `basic` worked, too. It seems that it overrides the Maven provided component with the same hint.