# Does <execution> have to be specified for a maven plugin to get executed?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I developed my own Maven plugin and annotated its Mojo as:

```
@Mojo(name="bt-hello-world", defaultPhase=LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
```

I use this plugin in another Maven project as:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.bt.maven.learning</groupId>
                <artifactId>app-one</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It wouldn't get executed. I then added `@Execute(goal="bt-hello-world", phase=LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, lifecycle="default")` to the Mojo in order to avoid using `<executions>`, but still doesn't work.

If I do add `<executions>` it does work. However, I have seen projects that use plugins without `<executions>` and their goals get executing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Those other plugins are bound into life cycle of Maven or define their own life cycle which I assume your's does not...

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40599913/1743880

Comment: Right. The plugin I mentioned defined its own lifecycle. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, I face the exact same pb but have not defined any own lifecycle. Executing "mvn help:describe -DartifactId=scm-graph-maven-plugin -DgroupId=com.teamtter.maven  -Ddetail" does give me "scm-graph:generate [...] Bound to phase: validate" but running "mvn validate" does not run my plugin. If I explicitly bind it to "validate" phase in <execution> then it's ok. I really don't know why... Can you help please ?

Comment: My plugin is visible there: https://github.com/fmarot/scm-graph-maven-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: First `@Execute...` is to fork a life cycle where I have doubts you would like to do..furthermore to get a plugin bound to the life cycle you need to define execution blocks for it....